# How to modify Heading 1 for specific indents in Word via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-style

I'm attempting to modify Heading 1 in Word to fit the following criteria:

```
Font: Bold, Indent:  
    Left:  0"  
    Hanging:  0.3", Space  
    Before:  18 pt  
    After:  6 pt, Level 1, Outline numbered + Level: 1 + Numbering Style: 1, 2, 3, … + Start at: 1 + Alignment: Left + Aligned at:  0" + Indent at:  0.3", Style: Show in the Styles gallery  
    Based on: Normal  
    Following style: Normal
```

I've included a screenshot of the Modify Style window for reference. The above text comes from the bottom portion of that screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of Heading 1 Style Window]

So far, I have the following outlined which takes care of the alignment, line spacing, and font, however I'm having some difficulties with the rest of the criteria, specifically the indent styles.

```vb
Sub ModifyHeading1()
    With ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1)
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
        .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpaceSingle
        .ParagraphFormat.IndentCharWidth 0 'Revisit this one
        .ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 0
        .ParagraphFormat.HangingPunctuation = 0.3
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 18
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6
        .ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevel1

        With .Font
             .Name = "Arial"
             .Size = 11
             .Bold = True
             .Color = wdColorAutomatic
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Let me know what I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try recording a macro while modifying the style? That will give you all the properties and values you need.

Comment: I would have never thought about recording. Here I was attempting this by hand. Thank you!